# How can someone do a describe_images to find the latest Ubuntu image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ami

I'm looking to find a way in Boto3 to get the latest Ubuntu image from Canonical. Regular describe_images() doesn't have a parameter for the Canonical.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
    #Canonical id = 099720109477
    images = ec2.describe_images(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'architecture',
                'Values': ['x86_64',]
            },
            {   'Name': 'root-device-type',
                'Values': ['ebs']
            },
            {
                'Name':  'name',
                'Values': ['ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server*']
            }
        ],
        Owners=['099720109477']
    )

    sortedAmis = sorted(images['Images'],
                  key=lambda x: x['CreationDate'],
                  reverse=True)


    lastestAMI = sortedAmis[0]['ImageId']
```

#returns: ami-01c132a30955dafbb

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Systems Manager (SSM) can be used to query the latest Ubuntu AMI ID from Canonical.

```
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
name = "/aws/service/canonical/ubuntu/server/18.04/stable/current/amd64/hvm/ebs-gp2/ami-id"
image_id = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name=name)['Parameter']['Value']
```

The path follows this format:

```
ubuntu/$PRODUCT/$RELEASE/stable/current/$ARCH/$VIRT_TYPE/$VOL_TYPE/ami-id
```

- PRODUCT: `server` or `server-minimal`
- RELEASE: `focal`, `20.04`, `bionic`, `18.04`, `xenial`, or `16.04`
- ARCH: `amd64` or `arm64`
- VIRT_TYPE: `pv` or `hvm`
- VOL_TYPE: `ebs-gp2`, `ebs-io1`, `ebs-standard`, or `instance-store`

From Canonical's [Cloud images - Amazon EC2](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/cloud-images/amazon-ec2)